# Putting the label of an angle at a specific polar coordinate

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-euclide

By default, the position of label of an angle is at the ray passing through the middle of an arc.
Is there a way to put the label at a point with a specific polar coordinate?

The motivation is that when there are too many rays, changing `pos` does not necessarily fit the label at the right place. One has to change the arc position of the label.

I tried `pos={(20:1.1)}` but it didn't work (i.e., I tried to put the label at the polar coordinate with the angle 20 degree and the length 1.1).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}%IMPORTANT--recognizes points, lines, circles, etc
\usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes,bending}



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{document}


\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\tkzDefPoint(1, 2){A}
\tkzDefPoint(3, 1){B} 
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){O}
\tkzDrawSegment(O,A)
\tkzDrawSegment(O,B)
\tkzMarkAngle[arc=ll,size=.85 cm](B,O,A)
\tkzLabelAngle[pos=1.1](A,O,B){$\beta$}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I find it difficult to figure out what you want to achieve. Your code compiles and puts the label at a good position. If you want to change the radial position of the label, you can either position a node absolutely with `\draw (20:1.1) node{$\beta$}` or shift your label relative to its current position with '[pos=1.1, shift={(20:0.2)}]`. With the latter way you can further shift a relative position along the path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coordinate transformations in `tikz` are additive (within reason). That is, you can provide coordinates absolutely (the `\tkzDefPoint` above), draw a line relative to the coordinates (`tkzMarkAngle`) based unrelated requirements (the `[size]`), add position a label along this path. The position here is given by `[pos=]`, resulting in a relative position along the path. This position can then be further refined using `[shift={(coordinate)}]` (which can take radial coordinates) and `xshift=`/`yshift=`. Note that the order here can be important. Additionally you can use the `above`, `left`, `right`, `below` keywords that give you pre-defined shifts (on a cartesian grid; has to be given before any numerical shifts). The position words such as `at end`, `very near end` and so on clash with `pos=` and cannot be used at the same time, `tikz` will take the last argument given.

So if you give `[pos=1.1, shift={(20:0.2)}, xshift=0.1]`, `tikz` will dutifully go to position 1.1 along your path, shift the position by 0.2 in a 20° direction and then shift it by 0.1 on the x axis.

Aside: Usually the `pos` argument goes from 0 to 1, with a logical extension in both directions if possible. I think the reason why `pos=1.1` works here has to do with the way that `tkzMarkAngle` is defined.